# fuseki fails to upload data to memory but sucess to TDB

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I have this free Ontology

http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/wine/wine.owl

I can **not** load it when using in memory service, but I can load it when using TDB service.

This is my config

```
@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
    fuseki:services (
 <#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    )
.

# TDB
    tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
    tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .

# ------ In memory with reasoner
<#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type fuseki:Service;
    rdfs:label "testdataset";
    fuseki:name "testdataset";
    fuseki:serviceQuery "query";
    fuseki:serviceUpdate "update";
    fuseki:dataset <#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> ;
.

<#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset;
    ja:defaultGraph <#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
.

<#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    ja:reasoner [ ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner>];
.
```

Am i doing something wrong?

**the problem that I am getting is**:

[image]

Again, loading the same file using TDB is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are running a version of Fuseki that does not recognize `.owl`. Try changing the file extension to `.rdf`.

(edited due to additional information)

The latest released version, 2.3.1, recognizes `.owl`.

The TDB service and memory service are presumably differently defined.

The service configuration shown does not have a loading service.

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html

For loading from the UI, you need the `fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore` (it uses the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol).

Comment: @TallTed what update please? i'm using the last version

Comment: I've already tried making it RDF instead of OWL and the same error happened

Comment: and by the way, it is not working even with .ttl , but all these files work with TDB instead of in memory

Comment: @AniaDavid -- The answer has been edited.  The changes may answer your comments...